# Unity to iOS debugger exception

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I exported my unity project and opened it xCode.

It compiled well but I then I get this

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   Il2CppExceptionWrapper

Im using the new ll2cpp compiler for the necessary 64 bit architecture.

How do I handle this exception?

Mirza